# Tesseract different results

Tags: python, imagemagick, jpeg, ocr, tesseract

i am using tesseract to detect text on images and pdfs. I have installed it on OSX El Capitan and its working very well. Additionally i installed it on a Ubuntu 16.04 Server. But its not performing very well. The results are different on the same images. Its the same version on both systems: Tesseract 4.00 Alpha, Leptonica 1.74.1

OSX

```
tesseract 4.00.00alpha
leptonica-1.74.1
libjpeg 8d : libpng 1.6.29 : libtiff 4.0.7 : zlib 1.2.5
```

Ubuntu

```
tesseract 4.00.00alpha
leptonica-1.74.1
libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.4.2) : libpng 1.2.54 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8
```

I am converting on both systems the image/pdf file into jpeg in python with imagemagick/libmagick-dev using the  Wand wrapper. I guess it has something to do with the jpeg encoding. Why does it behave like that?

```
    all_pages = WI(filename=args['image'], resolution=300)
    all_pages.compression_quality = 100
    #i set the compression type but this doesn't changed anything
    #all_pages.compression = 'jpeg2000'
    image_jpeg = all_pages.convert('jpg')

    single_image = WI(image=image_jpeg.sequence[0])
    blob = single_image.make_blob("jpg")

    single_image.close()
    all_pages.close()

    img = PI.open(BytesIO(blob)).convert("L")
    greyImg = np.array(img)
    # do some image processing

    pIm_bw = PI.fromarray(output)      
    builder = pyocr.builders.LineBoxBuilder()
    print("LineBoxBuilder set")
    txt = tool.image_to_string(
        pIm_bw,
        lang=language,
        builder=builder
    )
```

Comment: The problem occurs with the original file. When i save the file before i process it and load it again with opencv (imread) the results are the same on both systems. Why is that happening?

Comment: Does it happen if you use the same jpeg file?

Comment: Yes it happens on the same files.